# Android background HTTP Request does not work?

Tags: java, android

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageView imageView1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        imageView1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        imageView1.setImageBitmap(getBitMap());
    }
}   


    public void getBitMap() {
CompletetableFuture<BitMap> f = 
    CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() ->
                             {
                                    try {
                                        Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new URL(url).openStream());
                                        return b;
                                    } catch (IOException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                    return null;
                                }, Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10));

return f.get();
    }
```

I have noticed unusual behavior. This code does not work properly. Effectively, the image actually never ends up showing up. I did `f.get()` in the `getBitMap()` method which I thought would block until the `CompletableFuture` is not done.

Whats wrong with this approach?

Answer (score 0):

try adding `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` in your manifest, under application subunit

Comment: What does this do? Thanks!

Comment: android has restricted cleartext(http) communication in upper build versions, and this tag accepts that application may use it.
was that the problem anyway?